# Resizing background-image always proportionally to scale with a center point

Tags: css, background-image

I want to be able to reproduce the behavior of this website's image when resizing.

It seems like the background-image has a center point where the image start to crop when it cannot keep its proportion scale.

Here is an example:

http://themes.evgenyfireform.com/wp-jad/

For now my background has the following css:

```
#bg {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0px;
    width:100%;
}
```

The problem is that it's fixed and I want it to crop when the image can't be scale.

Comment: Do you have any code you can share? What attempts have you made so far?

Comment: For now my background has the following css:

#bg {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0px;
width:100%;
}

The problem is that it's fixed and I want it to crop when the image can't be scale.

Comment: This is probably what you're looking for: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You are looking for this combination:

```
background-position:50% 50%;  /* Sets reference point to scale from */
background-size:cover;        /* Sets background image to cover entire element */
```

[Working sample fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/zNE5A/).

Note that this is [not supported by IE8](http://caniuse.com/background-img-opts) and will require JS hackery there if you need IE8 or older to be supported.

Comment: This is cool, but how to solve the squeeze when lower width? possible auto scale with hight:100%?

Comment: Agreed this is cool, but I have found with Firefox 44 on CentOS 6, Xorg CPU usage goes up to nearly 100% permanently after resizing a window with a body using a large image in this manner. You have to restart Firefox to bring it back to normal. Developers might be advised to care about this bug.

Comment: image with lower height is not scaling proportionately. any workaround?

Comment: @fatCop impossible, `background-size:cover` is strictly defined to maintain aspect

Comment: This works well in combination with `padding` and `background-origin: content-box`