# How to correctly scale down the background image proportionally?

Tags: css

Currently, I create a 1288x200 image (https://jstock.org/images/banner.png).

I want it to shown as 100px height banner. The reason I'm using 2x height, as I want it to look good in retina display.

As you can see in current outcome, it doesn't look good - https://jstock.org/

[image]

I try to change from

```
.banner {
    height: 100px;
    background: #3B3E44 url('images/banner.png');
}
```

to

```
.banner {
    height: 100px;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background: #3B3E44 url('images/banner.png');
}
```

But, the outcome is still the same.

Can anyone provide me some hint, on how to scale down the background image proportionally?

Comment: Please include a [mcve]. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to do so.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resizing background-image always proportionally to scale with a center point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18323994/resizing-background-image-always-proportionally-to-scale-with-a-center-point)

Comment: `100% auto` on the background-size ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you set your background-size to `contain` so it contain your image in your height

```css
.banner {
    height: 100px;
    background: #3B3E44 url("https://jstock.org/images/banner.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! My mistake is I'm placing `background-repeat`, `background-size` and `background-position` before `background`. The order does matter?

Comment: But my testing shown that order does matter. Can you tested on your side, by moving `background: #3B3E44 url("https://jstock.org/images/banner.png");` to last? It seems that scaling will break.

Comment: order is matter when you add `background` css on that because `background` have own syntex, you can visit https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background/ this link and clear your doubt

Comment: when you use background-image, background-position, background-color then order is not matter